# How to store first row (headers) in one hash map from Excel sheet and store column data in another hashmap

Tags: java, excel, file, hashmap, hssfworkbook

```
Name,Branch,Collage ==> Headers in excel sheet
Sasi, CSE, JNTU-A
Sandeep, CIVIL, JNTU-H
```

I want set values like this and do some loop until last column of respective header.

```
("Name", "Sasi")
("Name", "Sandeep")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Apache POI. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("some_sheet.xlsx"));

        HashMap<Integer, String> headers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        HashMap<Object, String> cells = new HashMap<Object, String>();

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int colNum = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                headers.put(colNum++, cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int colNum = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                cells.put(getCharValue(cell), headers.get(colNum++));
            }
        }
        file.close();

        headers.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        });
        cells.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static Object getCharValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

            return cell.getNumericCellValue();

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You need the following Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:888)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:310)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:261)
 at bulkLoad.poc.readExcelSheet.main(readExcelSheet.java:61)

Comment: I have updated, didn't know u need Numbers. Now it should work, but i don't know whether a HashMap is the thing your are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

As per apache poi documentation `getStringCellValue()` throws exception if cell type is numeric.

As solution you can check type using `cell.getCellType()` and call relative `getXXXCellValue()` methods.